# response.setHeader Doesn't work in jsp file

Tags: jsp

I have to force an redirect action when i click a button, so i write this code:

```
<td><button name="cancella_e" value="<%=result.getString("ID")%>" onclick="">C </button>  </td>
```

and this is to manage the action of the click:

```
<%
        if(request.getParameter("modifica_e")!=null){
            String indice = request.getParameter("modifica_e");
            session.setAttribute("modificare","entrata");
            session.setAttribute("modificare_i",indice);
            response.setHeader("Refresh", "0.3; URL=modifica.jsp");
        }
%>
```

In some pages it works but in this particular page it doesn't work... I try to use java script suck as:

```
<%
        if(request.getParameter("modifica_e")!=null){
            String indice = request.getParameter("modifica_e");
            session.setAttribute("modificare","entrata");
            session.setAttribute("modificare_i",indice);
            %>
            <script>
                response.setHeader("Refresh", "0.3; URL=modifica.jsp");
            </script> 
            <%
}
%>
```

but it doesn't work to..

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are using scriplts (<%----%>) ?

I suggest that you add a form in your jsp and pass data to a servlet when button is clicked.And the servlet send data to the next jsp.

add this form to your JSP :

```
<form action="EXP_SERVLET" method="get">
//ADD THE DATA THAT YOU WANT TO PASS TO THE SERVLET
<input type="submit" value="<%=result.getString("ID")%>" />
</form>
```

2/Servlet :

```
public class EXP_SERVLET extends HttpServlet {


    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {


                if(request.getParameter("modifica_e")!=null){
            String indice = request.getParameter("modifica_e");
            request.getSession().setAttribute("modificare","entrata");
            request.getSession().setAttribute("modificare_i",indice);


     RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("modifica.jsp");
        view.forward(request, response); 
        }

    }}
```

Comment: Thanks. it's a school project and i don't know how to use servlet, but i sovle my problem usign javascript

<script>  top.location.href = "url"   </script>